# How do a manipulate the DOM in order to nest elements using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, dom

I have a test project where I am using Firebase as a way to render data on a HTML page. It works fine but I need to include more nested HTML (divs) with classes to maintain my layout. Is it possible to do this? I have following Javascript.

```
const productList = document.querySelector('#productList');

function renderProducts(doc) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let divInner = document.createElement('div');
    let title = document.createElement('h2');

    li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    title.textContent = doc.data().title;

    li.appendChild(divInner);
    li.appendChild(title);

    div.setAttribute('class', 'inner');
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    productList.appendChild(li);
}

db.collection('Products').get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        renderProducts(doc);
    })
})
```

However, this produces the following HTML, where obvisously nothing is nested. *Note I have removed the data for the purpose of explaining.

```
<ul id="productsList">
    <li>
        <div class="inner"></div>
        <h2></h2>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, my desired outcome would be to then somehow manipulate the DOM to move the `<h2>` inside the `<div>`;

```
<ul id="productsList">
    <li>
        <div class="inner">
            <h2></h2>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're already doing it a little - if you want h2 inside the div, use .appendChild() -- divInner.appendChild(title) for example.

Comment: you appended title to `li`. Try appending to `div` to get what you want.

Comment: Thought that's what I did with li.appendChild(divInner); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are appending it in wrong place.
Please try this one.

```
function renderProducts(doc) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let divInner = document.createElement('div');
    let title = document.createElement('h2');

    li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    title.textContent = doc.data().title;

    divInner.appendChild(title);
    li.appendChild(divInner);

    div.setAttribute('class', 'inner');
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    productList.appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: If the document.body.appendChild(div); part is removed, it work :)

Comment: Sure .. thank you for helping. I am starting to understand.